# Lack of Internet Connection Stops Cells from Being Created

Tags: ios, uitableview, plist, nsurlconnection

I am creating an app that takes a JSON text from a server and translates it into a match schedule for a robotics tournament. I have custom cells that are filled with the data I receive from the site and they display the data for each individual match just fine. The problem is that when I put the matches into a .plist file ("data.plist") so that once the internet connection is established initially, the user doesn't necessarily need to reconnect to the internet once the app is killed in order to view the match schedule for the day. My code works perfectly until I don't connect to the internet. For some reason, the app never goes into the function that creates the cells once the internet connection fails. Please help!! Here is my code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        aRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://jrl.teamdriven.us/source/scripts/getElimMatchResultsJSON.php"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];
        aConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:aRequest delegate:self];
        if(aConnection){
            receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
        }
        else{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Connection!!" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alert show];
        }

        paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        jrlDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        path = [jrlDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"data.plist"]) {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"] toPath:path error:nil];
        }

        dataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];    
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
        // Prevents data from repeating itself

        [receivedData setLength:0];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
        [receivedData appendData: data];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Failed" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
    }

    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

        NSLog(@"Success! Received %d bits of data", [receivedData length]);

        // Must allocate and initialize all mutable arrays before changing them

        sweet16 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        quarterfinals = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        semi = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        finals = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

        // The error is created and can be referred to if the code screws up (example in the "if(dict)" loop)

        NSError *error;
        dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
        matchNames = [[dict objectForKey:@"ElimMatchListResults"]allKeys];
        matchNames = [matchNames sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

        // Categorize the matches based on the first two letters of their match names

        for (NSString *name in matchNames) {
            if([[name substringToIndex:2]isEqual:@"16"]){
                 [sweet16 insertObject:[[dict objectForKey:@"ElimMatchListResults"] objectForKey:name] atIndex:sweet16.count];
            }
            else if([[name substringToIndex:2]isEqual:@"Q."]){
                 [quarterfinals insertObject:[[dict objectForKey:@"ElimMatchListResults"]objectForKey:name] atIndex:quarterfinals.count];
            }
            else if([[name substringToIndex:2]isEqual:@"S."]){
                [semi insertObject:[[dict objectForKey:@"ElimMatchListResults"]objectForKey:name] atIndex:semi.count];
            }
            else if([[name substringToIndex:2]isEqual:@"F."]){
                [finals insertObject:[[dict objectForKey:@"ElimMatchListResults"]objectForKey:name] atIndex:finals.count];
            }
        }

        headers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sweet 16", @"Quarterfinals", @"Semifinals", @"Finals", nil];
        sections = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sweet16, quarterfinals, semi, finals, nil];

        // If the dictionary "dict" gets filled with data...

        if (dict) {

            [[self tableView]setDelegate:self];
            [[self tableView]setDataSource:self];

            // Now uses data storage so that the user only needs to initially connect to the internet and then they can keep the schedule afterwords

            [dataDict setObject: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSArray arrayWithArray:sections], @"sections",
                                 [NSArray arrayWithArray:headers], @"headers",
                                                     nil]
                          forKey:@"Matches"];
             [dataDict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }

    }

    // Set the number of sections based on how many arrays the sections array has within it

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
       return [[[dataDict objectForKey:@"Matches"] objectForKey:@"sections"] count];
    }

    // Set the number of rows in each individual section based on the amount of objects in each array
    //   within the sections array

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        return [[[[dataDict objectForKey:@"Matches"] objectForKey:@"sections"] objectAtIndex:section] count];
    }

    // Set headers of sections from the "headers" array

    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        return [[[dataDict objectForKey:@"Matches"] objectForKey:@"headers"] objectAtIndex:section];
    }

    // Create cells as the user scrolls

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


        NSLog(@"Entered Final Loop");

        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if(!cell){
            cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.matchNum.text = [[[[[dataDict objectForKey:@"Matches"] objectForKey:@"sections"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"MatchID"];
        cell.red1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[[[dataDict objectForKey:@"Matches"] objectForKey:@"sections"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Red 1"]];
        cell.red2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[[[dataDict objectForKey:@"Matches"] objectForKey:@"sections"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Red 2"]];
        cell.redScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[[[dataDict objectForKey:@"Matches"] objectForKey:@"sections"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Red Score"]];
        cell.blue1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[[[dataDict objectForKey:@"Matches"] objectForKey:@"sections"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Blue 1"]];
        cell.blue2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[[[dataDict objectForKey:@"Matches"] objectForKey:@"sections"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Blue 2"]];
        cell.bluescore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[[[dataDict objectForKey:@"Matches"] objectForKey:@"sections"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Blue Score"]];


        return cell;
    }
```

I apologize for the lengthy code, I'm just trying to make sure I got all the details in. Please ask any questions you need to in order to clarify, I'm just really stuck and flustered right now as to why it never enters the function that creates cells if it doesn't have an internet connection.

Comment: If your `-tableView:cellforRowAtIndexPath:` isn't being called, then it's probably because the table view doesn't exist, or you're not setting its data source properly, or (most likely) `-tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:` or `-numberOfSectionsInTableView:` is returning 0 for some reason. Use the debugger to check these things. What is `dataDict` after the connection fails?

Comment: I checked and dataDict was (nil), so I created a path to the plist if the connection failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my solution. The

```
    [[self tableView]setDelegate:self];
    [[self tableView]setDataSource:self];
```

Was only located in the "connectionDidFinishLoading:" function, so the data sources were never set if there was no internet connection.

I really appreciated everyone's help in this problem and I have edited a lot of my code to make it work better based off of those suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of reactions:

1. Your `fileExistsAtPath` doesn't look right. Surely you should have fully qualified path, e.g.:

   ```
   if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
       [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"] toPath:path error:nil];
   }
   ```

   I'd also probably suggest you check the success of `copyItemAtPath` (either the return value or use the `error` parameter).
2. I assume you know that the `data.plist` will never be successfully refreshed before `viewDidLoad` finishes (because the connection is initiated asynchronously and you return immediately from `initWithRequest`). This code is just loading the last `data.plist` values while retrieving the new data proceeds (the previous error notwithstanding). Is that your expectation?
3. On top of my prior point, your `connectionDidFinishLoading` does not appear to be issuing a `reloadData` call for the table, so it seems like you'll always see the previous data. When the connection is done, `connectionDidFinishLoading` should call `reloadData` for the `UITableView`.
4. Minor, unrelated detail, but I'd probably initialize `receivedData` in the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` method `didReceiveResponse` (and only if that response was successful, too). It doesn't really belong in `viewDidLoad`.
5. I might also encourage you to check for failure of `JSONObjectWithData`. Some networking failures manifest themselves as a successful `NSURLConnection` request that returns an HTML page (!) reporting an error. That HTML page will fail `JSONObjectWithData` processing. You might want to abort your parsing routine if `JSONObjectWithData` returns `nil` or if the `error` object is not `nil`.

Comment: The .plist file gets created and read just fine, I was just wondering why the cells weren't being created. I appreciate the modifications for the internet connection side of that though. Is there a chance that you know how to easily make a refresh button work? Or even better, have it refresh every 30 seconds or so on its own? (provided that it's connected to the internet, of course)

Comment: @teamDriven1730 The plist will be created, but I wager that if you put in a `NSLog` statement in there, you'll see it being recreated _after_ the table is loaded. Or it will do that on a slow connection. (Try using the network link conditioner to simulate slower network conditions.) In terms of making refresh button work, move this `URLConnection` code into a separate `retrieveData` method (or whatever) and (a) call that from `viewDidLoad`; (b) call that from the refresh button; and (c) make sure your `connectionDidFinishReloading` calls `reloadData` for the table view.

Comment: @teamDriven1730 In terms of reloading every 30 seconds, you could have `NSTimer` call this `retrieveData` method, too. But every 30 seconds is pretty aggressive (it will drain battery, consume the user's data plan if doing it on cellular, it would be jarring if the user had scrolled down the table view and it suddenly refreshed on them, etc.). If you're determined to do frequent polling of your server, only do so if the user is not on cellular connection (which you can determine using [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)).

Comment: @teamDriven1730 By the way, if you're going to request data looking for updates, I'm not sure I'd use `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy`. You might want `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData` if you really want to re-retrieve the data. (By the way, if you're caching, that might contribute to false impression of speed of data retrieval from your server.)

Comment: Put all of it in the code and it works great. Really appreciate the help. I put in a function to refresh and made a button to call it. I also implemented the use of an NSTimer to disable the refresh button for 5 seconds after pressing it so that the user doesn't spam the server. The page works beautifully now and I am super stoked! Thanks!!